# Application crashed some times but not in debug mode

Tags: java, android

I have a strange situation in which my application is getting crashed sometime(say after doing nearly 20 transaction) but in debug mode its not happening even in emulator the crashed doesn't occurred.
I have increase my heap memory too.

The Log error i'm attaching here:

```
 07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:492)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:93)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.mis.adapter.MicListAdapter.<init>(MicListAdapter.java:52)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.mis.controller.InventoryCount$InflateList.onPostExecute(InventoryCount.java:3061)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.mis.controller.InventoryCount$InflateList.onPostExecute(InventoryCount.java:1)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here i have attached my onPostMethod()

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<MIC_OrderDetails> lst) {
            dialog.setMessage("Inflating Data...");
            if (lst.get(lst.size() - 1).getResult().contains(("success"))) {
                ordList = new MicListAdapter(InventoryCount.this, lst);
                lstView.setAdapter(ordList);
                dialog.dismiss();
            } else {
                dialog.dismiss();
                toastText.setText("Problem in loading Items");
                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 410);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setView(toastLayout);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you show your adapter?

Comment: If your data is huge don't load everything into memory. Why don't you use a load more button that loads the data in batches. I am not sure about the size of data you have but this is generally the best practice when loading large amount of data.

Comment: You have obvious error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. So you code depleted heap memory. Problem could be a MemoryLeak, but if you say in debug mode is ok... i expect your GarbageCollector isn't able allocate  new memory as fast as you deplete it (or heap is on max)... pointing to configuration problem. Anyway you should reduce creating object (reuse old one) and throw unneeded (set to null) as soon as possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't recreate the adapter again in `onPostExecute()` method. Instead create the adapter once in `onCreate()` method and use `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` in `onPostExecute()` method. Something like this,

Create your dataset `list` as a class variable and initialize it before `onCreate()` like this,

```
List<MIC_OrderDetails> list = new ArrayList<MIC_OrderDetails>();
```

Inside onCreate method initialize the adapter,

```
adapter = new MicListAdapter(InventoryCount.this, list);
lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Inside onPostExecute method,

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<MIC_OrderDetails> lst) {
    dialog.setMessage("Inflating Data...");
    if (lst.get(lst.size() - 1).getResult().contains(("success"))) {
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(lst);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        dialog.dismiss();
    } else {
        dialog.dismiss();
        toastText.setText("Problem in loading Items");
        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 410);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(toastLayout);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: EveryTime the application enter this screen i'm getting the data from the database and inflating it in the Listview.So that if data is huge it wont hindered the Main UI thread.So i have created the adpter in the onPostExcute method..Please correct me if i'm wrong anywhere..

Comment: @K Nerraj Lal I tried the way you adviced but still out of Memory issue persist..Any idea???

Comment: @PraneshSahu Is the crash log still same? Please update the code.

Comment: I have solved it by Calling finish() in my Custom Dialog but stuck with new issue that my Listview doesn't refresh @K Neeraj Lal

Answer (score 0):

if you have to process huge data, please add `android:largeHeap="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml.